# Getting the name of a stdClass object in PHP

Tags: php, object

I'm playing with an API that's giving me data back in JSON format that I then `json_decode()` to the following format:

```
[stockData] => stdClass Object
    (
        [data] => stdClass Object
            (
                [PS3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [2015-01-26T20:45:01Z] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [AMU] => 999.76
                                [ZIT] => 3.63
                            )

                    )

            )

        [status] => stdClass Object
            (
                [code] => 200
                [text] => ok
            )

    )
```

I need some way of getting the `2015-01-26T20:45:01Z` (which changes all the time).

I've tried `get_Class()` on the object, eg:

`get_Class($bawsaq->stockData->data->PS3)` (actually in a `foreach` loop)

But all that's returned is: "stdClass" and not the name. How can I get the object's name?

Comment: Why don't use the second argument to `json_decode()` so it returns arrays instead of objects?

Comment: `2015-01-26T20:45:01Z` isn't the class name, it's a property name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't actually the object's class: it's the name of the property that contains the `stdClass` object. So you'd need to get the first object property name from `$bawsaq->stockData->data->PS3`. Which is a bit tricky, actually.

It's nicer to work with arrays. If you use the [`$assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) parameter of `json_decode`, you can get an associative array instead of an object whenever a JSON object appears. This is much easier to deal with in PHP.

```
$bawsaq = json_decode($jsonData, true);
```

You can get the key name with [`key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php):

```
$dateTime = key($bawsaq['stockData']['data']['PS3']);
```

Comment: Wonderful. I like dealing with objects normally, but clearly arrays are nicer in times like this. Thanks!

Comment: Generally I'll work in objects too, but almost never with stdClass ones. Glass to help.

Answer (score 5):

When you decode the JSON, use

```
$bawsaq = json_decode($json, true);
```

This will return associative arrays instead of `stdClass` objects for all the JSON objects. Then you can use

```
$keys = array_keys($bawsaq['stockData']['data'];
$date = $keys[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) method.

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->field1 = 'value1';

print_r(get_object_vars($obj));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [field1] => value1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second argument to [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). This will return the data as an associative array instead of an object list, so you could simply use

```
$input = json_decode($jsonInput, true);
$key = key($input['stockData']['data']['PS3']);
$data = $input['stockData']['data']['PS3'][$key];
```

or a foreach-loop. See also [`key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) on php.net.

Comment: That wont work it would jsut make the reference look like: `$input['stockData']['data']['PS3']['2015-01-26T20:45:01Z']`